# Groovy: copy file, while converting line endings

Tags: groovy, io, conventions, line-endings

I am using Groovy to customize Maven assembly plugin and make my life a bit easier. Basically I would like to mimicry Maven Assembly plugin functionallity and one is to copy files while converting line endings.

What is the simplest way to copy file from A to B while converting line-endings to Unix-style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this (assuming the file is not too large, as it loads it all into memory)

```
void convertCRLF( File input, File output ) {
    output << input.text.replaceAll( '\r\n', '\n' )
}

convertCRLF( new File( '/tmp/test.txt' ), new File( '/tmp/test.fix.txt' ) )
```

Or maybe you could try AntBuilder with [the FixCRLF task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html)

An example of this would be:

```
new AntBuilder().fixcrlf( srcDir:'/tmp/inputs', eol:'lf' )
```

Which will convert all files in `/tmp/inputs` to use `lf` as the line-ending

Comment: Don't like this solution, because it based over some assumption of how initial file is formatted (windows-style in the example). I don't have this kind of information. Is there a way to convert ANY text file to Unix-style one?

Comment: @DenisKulagin If it's unix based (with just `\n`), it won't touch it.  I'll have a look into an example of the AntBuildter task

Comment: Yes, it won't. But if I try to convert file the other way it will generate some nasty mix of \r's and \r\n's.

Comment: @DenisKulagin Added an example of using the `fixcrlf` task via `AntBuilder`